# Best way to prevent a user from selecting None/Others before reading all available options

Tags: user-behavior, selection

I am making an insurance related form where only "none" is selected option in the list of occupation. 
What is the best way represent it so that user go through all options before selecting "None".

I am currently using a drop-down with 'None of the above' as last option.

An example to clear what I am asking -  let's say there are 5000 models of cars and only 50 of them are not allowed. I want user(its given that every user owns a car) to select none if user don't own any of those 50 cars.

Comment: I don't understand - if there is only one acceptable answer, why even bother with a list? (I'm not a native English speaker, so please forgive me if it's obvious for people with better language skill)

Comment: @Molot In surveys and such, you want to filter out people who have certain occupations, such as "Survey-making professional", since they are too likely to game the system.

Comment: How many choices a user can make? One or multiple?

Comment: @Molot I have edited my question​ for more clear understanding

Comment: I think the issue is to prevent a user from selecting `None` before reading all available options (which may include a more correct option than `None`).

Comment: @chepner That is a good interpretation of the question. Suvendra, can you change the question title to use chepner's interpretation (if it is correct?). Something like: **Best way to prevent a user from selecting None before reading all available options**

Comment: @Kodos Johnson edited the title as per your suggestion.

Comment: @KodosJohnson: Unfortunately, the changed title has now invalidated most of the top-voted answers so far. And the question text is still very confusing, and it's not 100% clear to me whether the new title *really* means what the OP actually intended to ask. Of course, arguably, the users who answered this question in its original unclear state knowingly took the risk that their answers might get downvoted or deleted after the question was clarified. Still, this whole thread is a mess now, and probably ought to have been put on hold long ago.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I agree that the question should have been closed long ago, but I disagree that the changed title invalidates any of the answers. I contend that they were already invalid because the title wasn't clear enough. The original title asked how to keep None of the above as the only acceptable answers and the top-voted answers just showed how to make it more prominent.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Also, my suggested title pretty much matches the OP's opening paragraph (i.e. *What is the best way represent it so that user go through all options before selecting "None".*). The OP was free to use or discard my suggestion. I even gave a disclaimer to use my suggestion if that was what they wanted to say.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It depends on the context and how much options the user have, let's assume that the user will select the brand of the car he has and there are many options, but the user does not own a car, so if the user has to click on the dropdown will be an unnecessary action since he does not own a car .

So I think of something like this:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fENDTW.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

I hope I have helped :)

**EDIT:**

Assuming that every user has a car, then he needs to select a brand in the dropdown and that dropdown has a filter to make the search easier.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foSS0z.png)</sup>

Comment: Maybe the contrary? [_] I have a job. if the user checks the box then it asks for the specific information with a dropdown that has "Other" as its last item.

Comment: True, it can be seen this way too.

Comment: @beppe9000 true; I think it really depends on what option is most common.  If 90% of users have a car, the above is preferable.

Comment: @dan1111 you are right

Comment: Perhaps a better option would be to first ask "Number of vehicles owned", then if the answer is >0, ask for vehicle 1, 2...

Comment: @MaisaBarros that is a good answer, but what I am asking is a bit different, let's say there are 5000 models of cars and only 50 of them are not allowed. I want user(its given that every user owns a car) to select none if user don't own any of those 50 cars.

Comment: @suvendrakumar ok, so assuming that every user has a car and he needs to select the brand from the list, and if that list has many values ​​the user can waste a lot of time trying to find the item he wants, I'll edit my answer with another interface option according to this comment.

Answer (score 33):

Even if the list goes too long - you can apply a scroll to the white space and keep 'None of above' always visible:

Radio buttons - Thanks @user1306322

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1H]

Comment: Imagine a world where everyone is either an insurance underwriter or a sales manager...

Comment: More seriously, the disadvantage of this is that it might not be obvious that there are more options than those displayed, so some might select "None of the above" even when it isn't true. In this case, perhaps "Software engineer" is below the first screen but I don't notice that the white box is scrollable; I'd probably just click "None of the above".

Comment: And as so often happens in real life, it doesn't even include  a "None of your damn business" option.

Comment: @Muzer he has just repeated the labels for this demo. Shouldn't be hard to understand right?

Comment: @Diego Humor. Shouldn't be hard to understand, right?

Comment: I don't think this is a great idea because no way user can search for his occupation except for him going through each one of them.

Comment: Please use radiobuttons instead of checkboxes if multiple choices are not expected. We're on UX.SE.

Comment: Actually the OP wants to make sure all the options are visible before seeing the None of the above option. So this answer is the exact opposite of what they want.

Comment: I agree with Kodos Johnson; how does this solve the OP's problem of too many people selecting the "none of the above" option? If anything, this seems to make it _easier_ for users to select the option the OP wants to discourage. Could you clarify this?

Comment: @11684: This *was* an (arguably) correct answer to the question before its title was "clarified". Unfortunately, the question text itself is still hard to make any sense of, and I'm not 100% convinced that the OP really understands enough English to tell if [the title they were told to use](https://ux.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/174018) actually matches the question they want to ask or not. IMO, the whole question is a hopeless mess and probably should've been put on hold long ago.

Answer (score 7):

"None of the above" is understandable, but I would go for a solution like "Other". I believe that it is more common practice for a dropdown and it has a positive message, rather than the negative message of "None of the above".

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frVwIn.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: The option 'Other' gives birth to another text field where users have to enter other occupation - it extends the task.

Comment: @DPS It doesn't need to. The designer can decide to extend it or not. "Other" can be sufficient enough. It is the same as "None of the above". None of the above could also be used to extend the task

Comment: For 'Other' option I have experienced systems showing additional text-field, not for the 'none of the above'.

Comment: @DPS Still, it is the designer's choice not to ask for further information. Don't you think?

Comment: It's never a designer's choice, it's either a business' or user's choice to obtain or provide information.

Comment: True, when I say designer's choice I am mean business choice. But since they have the option "None of the above" without asking for more information, they can also have "Other" without asking for more information.

Comment: I think, we have to consider the already set patterns and what the users would expect in this case.

Comment: @DPS Then this could be a good user test case ;)

Comment: @DPS, *this* user thinks "other" is just fine without a box for additional information.  That's why you often see "other (please specify)," right?

Answer (score 7):

Don't.

Present a plaintext list of the 50 disallowed models, followed by a checkbox saying "I hereby declare that my car is not one of these".

The user shall check or not check that box.

Comment: Although *certify* or *affirm* are probably better choices for the verb than *declare* here.  And "hereby" is just noise.

Comment: This will make the user interpret the checkbox as some kind of legal thing ("What if I make a mistake?  Will I get in trouble?").  That may or may not be appropriate for a given use case (agreeing to some legal terms -> Yes, filling out an optional survey -> No).

Comment: @Kevin: OP is creating an "insurance related form", so it probably _is_ a legal thing, and they probably _will_ get in trouble for lying.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that the best way is to positively identify the make and model of car in question and then have a automated process to determine whether it is eligible or not.

simply making the user choose from a list of every possible car is going to result in a very clunky form.

In the UK at least it is possible to identify the make and model from the registration number and, in my experience this is what most insurance forms do. If this is impractical a selection tree of Make>>Model>>Type(engine size/body style etc) is still a lot easier than trying to find the one you are interested in from a long list.

With a list you are forcing users to scan every single item to ensure it does not apply to them, if this is more than half a dozen items they are likely to either give up or make an error.

To put it another way it is much easier to find a specific item on a list than to  check every single item on a list to make sure it doesn't apply to you.

Comment: @Cris Johns The car model was just an example to clarify my question

Answer (score 2):

For OP's specific problem, don't make it a option/radio selection. Make it a yes/no question:

> Do you own one of the following models of vehicle? ...

Alternatively, if you're concerned they'll miss their model among the noise, or that they'll guess the reason you're asking and try to pretend they accidentally answered wrong, make it a freeform text entry box and interpret their response later.

Answer (score 0):

How about two fields:

One field asks the user whether they have a whatever (e.g. a car) and has two radio buttons - "Yes" and "No".

The second field, usually hidden but shown if the user clicks Yes on the first field, offers a Combobox of items (e.g. cars) to choose from.

Comment: Not really helpful for choosing an *occupation* from a list.  There is simply no way to have *every* possible occupation covered in a dropdown list of occupations.

Comment: @Wildcard: Something like [Select2](https://select2.github.io/) might be handy.

Comment: Perhaps, but for an insurance-related form I doubt it would give any benefit over just a free-form text field.

Comment: Possibly not, I suppose it all depends on context.

Answer (score 0):

Well, obviously, you just ask them about each of the disallowed models in turn.

First dialog:

```
"Is your car an Alpha Romeo Giulia?"
   [YES] [NO]
```

If [NO], then ask:

```
"Is your car a Beta Beetle?"
   [YES] [NO]
```

... continue for 48 more dialogs, up to ...

```
"Is your car a Zebra Impala?"
   [YES] [NO]
```

That way, you know they read all the available options.

(Hey, this approach works for the people that design "customer service" voicemail systems)